# Google Docs - Read only access, can I pass that on to a token?

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I've had a google doc shared with me. 
I only have read only access to this document.

Can **I** can generate a token such that I can programatically access this document that I have access to, but not ownership of.

The reason is the people who are sharing this with me are not technically savvy and won't be using Google's API console.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean generate a token from your end (using your own account), that would grant you access to a file (owned by different account) beyond what was originally shared (e.g. read-only to editor) to you?

Comment: Yes to everything except the part about beyond what was originally shared. I only want access exactly as much as my account has access to.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge yes, the link below will show you a table with all the permission. At least for spreadsheets, I haven't used other documents

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing